# Why can't I jump, or jump well?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now I'm not getting much Out of this. Depending on what I do different i either end up with an infinite loop, or poor jumping ability. I used a timer to tick my jumped bool but I was getting a double like jump ability and my ground detection wasn't good enough. Can you See why I can't jump, or jump well?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 0.05f;
    public float jumpVelocity = 0.05f;
    public bool onGround = true;
    public bool jumped = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        //test if player is on the ground
        if (onGround) { jumped = false; }

        // USER CONTROLS HERE.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && onGround == true) 
        {
            jumped = true;

            while(jumped) 
            {
                this.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpVelocity));

                if (onGround) { jumped = false; }
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
        {
            this.transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
        {
            this.transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "floor") { onGround = true; }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
    {       
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "floor") { onGround = true; }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from a misunderstanding how the Update method and physics work. If you do this in the update method, it will create an endless loop:

```
while(jumped) 
{
    this.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpVelocity));

    if(onGround)
    {
        jumped = false;
    }
}
```

The thing is that you tell the physics body to add a force. But you keep doing so over and over again. The physics simulation only takes place **after** the Update method returns, so whatever "onGround" is it will never become true because the forces aren't being applied until after the Update method.

Instead you have to make this check over and over again every time the Update method runs until onGround is true.

Comment: Sorry, I only understood you partially. I'm not too quick with this stuff... I did use a timer to switch off jumped in the while loop. This was allowing me to get airborne, but I was able to do a double jump sometimes... and could only jump at certain times... there was one tile i couldn't jump from at all... umm... you wouldn't know any good resources on this?

Comment: Oh, shoot. I get ya... It's going through the loop seeing that player is on the ground, no force added... hmm...

Comment: I got this figured out. The brick that was giving me trouble was tagged '8' instead of 'floor'. I was assigning my first tag and seen numbers, looked like array indexes.. didn't know what I was doing... guess I missed that tile after figuring it out..